# Reflection through multiple mirrors

Tags: reflection

Two plane mirrors are arranged at right angles to each other. A ray of light is incident on the horizontal mirror at an angle X. For what value of X does the ray emerges parallel to the incoming ray after reflection from the vertical mirror?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you

- assume optical geometrics rules,
- note that no change of medium is implied by the exercise

you may conclude that incident angle = reflection angle on both mirrors, such that if X is the first incidence angle, calculated with respect to the first mirror, the second reflection angle is given by 90-X, calculated with respect to the second mirror.

If the first incident ray is inclined X with respect to the horizontal, will incide on the second at an angle 90°-X, so it will be reflected at 90°+X, i.e. with an inclination of X;

so, the incident on the 1st, and the reflected on the 2nd, will always be parallel independently from X;

Comment: I felt the same but just wanted to confirm

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange.  Please browse the help system to discover the goals of the forum, and for suggestions on answering questions.  Note that we do not give complete answers to questions that are (or might be) homework questions.  In those cases, we provide suggestions to guide the OP to finding the answer him or herself, provided the question has expressed confusion about some point of physics.  If the question appears to be just a copy of a homework question (as at least two people think is the case here) we ask the OP what is the difficulty.  We don't provide the answer.

Comment: understood, apologize!

Comment: Iam  sorry for that. Will take care later on. For this question there was no difficulty . Just wanted a second opinion